# django avatar upload default value

Tags: django, image, templates, upload

I got a profile page where I can upload an avatar pic, but when there is no avatar there is this weblink "False"
[image]

How can I change it to "No Image" string and to remove the weblink tag as well?

Is it intended to work as a weblink to the default image?

This template uses {{ form.as_p }} to output a page.

Comment: share your model please

Comment: if you have this project on GitHub I can send you a pull request

Comment: Thank you sir, here it is: https://github.com/Gargooie/DJango-image-upload-test/

Comment: I sent you the request on github